# vscode launching function app in lerna monorepo

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, lerna, monorepo

First, I have a monorepo that is structured like so:

```
repo-name/
    packages/
        backend/
        frontend/
    .vscode/
```

The backend is an Azure function app structured like so:

```
backend/
    functions/
        funcOne/
        funcTwo/
    scripts/
        start-debug.sh
    package.json
```

Second, for the `backend`'s `package.json`, I have a script:

```
  "debug": "npm run build && FUNCTION_APP_PORT=7071 ./scripts/start-debug.sh",
```

The `start-debug.sh` script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash 
set -e
cd ./functions 
func extensions install 
func host start -p $FUNCTION_APP_PORT --debug VSCode
```

I'm trying to write a launch configuration so that I can debug my functions in VSCode.

I have tried a number of variations based on what I have found out there, but nothing seems to work.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Here's my latest attempt:

```
{
    "name": "Launch Backend Functions",
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "address": "localhost",
    "protocol": "inspector",
    "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/lerna",
    "runtimeArgs": [
        "exec",
        "--scope",
        "actual-name-of-backend-package",
        "--",
        "npm"
    ],
    "args": ["run", "debug"],
    "port": 1234
}
```

Comment: Hey
I've written a small vscode extension that can help you differentiate easily when you're working on a serverside file and a clientside file based on regex and colors. Maybe helpful to you!
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=orepor.color-tabs-vscode-ext#overview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here's the launch configuration in VSCode that worked for me:

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "attach",
  "name": "Attach by Process ID",
  "protocol": "legacy",
  "processId": "${command:PickProcess}",
  "port": 9229
},
```

My steps are

1) Go to my `backend` repo, and run `npm run debug` which runs my `start-debug.sh` script.

2) In VS Code, I attach to a `nodejsWorker` out of `azure-function-core-tools`.

Now, I can step through my functions.